# symfony 2 error on multiple embedded form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a strange error on a multiple embedded form with symfony2.

Here is my structure :

Licensee <- **OneToMany** -> Registration <- **OneToMany** -> Payment

**Licensee**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration", mappedBy="licensee", cascade={"persist" })
 */
private $registrations;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->registrations = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addRegistration(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration $registration)
{
    $this->registrations[] = $registration;
    $registration->setLicensee($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeRegistration(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration $registration)
{
    $this->registrations->removeElement($registration);
}

public function setRegistrations(ArrayCollection $registrations)
{
    foreach ($registrations as $registration) {
        $registration->addLicensee($this);
    }

    $this->registrations = $registrations;
}

public function getRegistrations() {
    return $this->registrations;
}
```

**Registration**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Licensee", inversedBy="registrations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $licensee;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Payment", mappedBy="registration", cascade={"ALL"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $payments;

public function __construct() {
    $this->payments = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Set licensee
 *
 * @param \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Licensee $licensee
 * @return Registration
 */
public function setLicensee(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Licensee $licensee)
{
    $this->licensee = $licensee;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get licensee
 *
 * @return \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Licensee 
 */
public function getLicensee()
{
    return $this->licensee;
}

/**
 * Add payments
 *
 * @param \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Payment $payment
 * @return Registration
 */
public function addPayment(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Payment $payment)
{
    $payment->setRegistration($this);
    $this->payments[] = $payment;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove payments
 *
 * @param \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Payment $payment
 */
public function removePayment(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Payment $payment)
{
    $this->payments->removeElement($payment);
}

/**
 * Get payments
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPayments()
{
    return $this->payments;
}
```

**Payment**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration", inversedBy="payments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $registration;

/**
 * Set registration
 *
 * @param \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration $registration
 * @return Payment
 */
public function setRegistration(\cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration $registration)
{
    $this->registration = $registration;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get registration
 *
 * @return \cM\ManagementBundle\Entity\Registration 
 */
public function getRegistration()
{
    return $this->registration;
}
```

**LicenseeType**:

```
$builder
        ->add('registrations', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new RegistrationType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
```

**RegistrationType**:

```
$builder
        ->add('payments', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new PaymentType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required'     => false,
        ))
```

**PaymentType**:

```
$builder
        ->add('amount', 'text')
```

My Main controller : **LicenseeController**

```
$form = $this->createForm('cm_managementbundle_licensee', $licensee);
$form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($licensee);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
    }
}
```

In the Licensee Form, a registration is mandatory, but payments are optionals.

- When i create a new licensee with registration info and **without** Payment : its ok and information are well saved in database
- when i edit the licensee and add some Payments : its ok
- when i create a new licensee with registration info and **with** one or more Payments, there is a doctrine error saying registration cannot be null:

  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Registration (registrationDate, registrationNumber, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)' with params [null, null, ...]:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'registrationDate' cannot be null

When i look to symfony profiler i see that doctrine launch 2 queries for the Registration table :

```
- "START TRANSACTION"
- INSERT INTO Licensee (lastname, firstname, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)
Parameters: { 1: Simpson, 2: Homer, ... }
- INSERT INTO Registration (registrationDate, registrationNumber, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)
Parameters: { 1: '2015-01-29 00:00:00', 2: '1234', ... }
- INSERT INTO Registration (registrationDate, registrationNumber, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)
Parameters: { 1: null, 2: null, ... }
```

Sow why is there a second Registration query with all the params to null while the first is correct?

What am i missing?

Thanks for any king of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to resolve this.

i have to change the prototype name of the Payment Collection

```
->add('payments', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new PaymentType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'prototype_name' => 'payments_name'
))
```

so when I dynamically change the name with javascript when I add a new Payment, I dont change the parent name (Registration) in the process (by default, all prototype collection have the same name (**name**)

Thanks to 
[Waiting for Dev...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208662/3725989) for the tips